# Is 18 AWG wire with peeling outer insulation still good to use?

Tags: electrical, wiring, recessed-lighting

I am changing my can lights to LED can lights using the Halo retrofit lights. [Can Lights I am using](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-LT56-Series-5-in-6-in-Selectable-CCT-3000-5000K-Integrated-LED-White-Recessed-Light-Dimmable-Retrofit-Trim-LT56069FS351EWHR/316521977)

Unfortunately my house has two different style can lights. One has the normal E26 screw type and the other cans have 4 Pin CFLs. I watches several YouTube tutorials on how to convert 4 pin CFL can to LED by removing the ballast and taking out two of the four wires. Then wire the remaining two to the main line 14/2. This is where my current issue is. After removing two of the wires (one red and one blue) I noticed that the clear insulation, at least I think it's insulation, around the wire is peeling off and I am not sure if the wire are still good to use.

As you can see in the image, the clear insulation is just lifting off. So couple questions.

1. Are these wire still OK to use? If yes, any electrical hazard arcing, fire, etc...?
2. What causes something like this?
3. If the wires are **not** OK to use, can I just run new wire in the can light conduit replacing those existing wires? Basically re-wiring the can light with new cable. If yes, what kind of wire should I buy.

Thank you.

[image]

Updated: Extra pics

[image: Halo Connector]

[image: diagram]

[image: Connections in can]

Comment: Can you post a photo showing where those wires lead?

Comment: I added some extra pictures to the post and a hand drawn diagram.

Answer (score 7):

I rebuild real fluorescent fixtures with modern ballasts and use them as fluorescent (rather than convert to LED).

What you're looking at there is TFN or TFFN wire. [Very similar to THHN wire](https://www.awcwire.com/allied-university/this-vs-that/tffn-vs-thhn), but in #16 or #18 size.  It's a mainstay inside any fluorescent fixture.  It is 600V-rated, has colored PVC insulation and a clear nylon outer jacket just like THHN.

In fact they are linear; TF(F)N exists from size #18 to #16, and THHN exists at #14 and larger.  I think the naming is mainly to remind installers that #18 and #16 wires are not allowed in walls; #14 minimum there. I see no problem using THHN inside a fixture, except that usually the lampholders are rated only for #18 solid.

It looks like the outer nylon jacket has taken some thermal damage, probably from the ballast.

I would replace it.  THHN wire is an ideal replacement since it is more readily available.

Comment: @harper-reinstate-monica reading the info in the link I have TFN (Solid core) #18 wire. At home depot's they do have #14 THHN wire both Solid and Stranded. Any advantage using one versus the other? I was thinking using solid since I am using push connectors which are easier to use with solid. The connection is not going to a lapholder. I am splicing the Halo connector to the wire coming from the the conduit. See updated pics in post

Also do I have too many splices (3) in such a short run of cable? 1 at the metal box were the ballast was, 1 at the wago and 1 at the Halo connector, 3 total?

Answer (score 0):

its good to use, the PVC insulation is still intact.

this nylon skin may be only a US specification here in BR those wires doesn`t even have it.

Comment: "**Damage to the nylon jacket only**, does not constitute damage to the insulation. The nylon jacket does provide mechanical protection to the insulation during and after installation and also provides gasoline and oil resistance for the wire. The question concerning replacement of the damaged wire can only be answered by visually examining the wire to understand the extent of the damage; and if the PVC insulation is damaged, or **if the conductor is exposed to gas and oil**, then replacing the wire may be necessary."

Comment: https://iaeimagazine.org/columns/ul-question-corner/if-the-nylon-on-thhn-is-scuffed-is-the-insulation-damaged/

Comment: yeah, of course, the part on the photo looks perfectly fine . this is the visual examination . but of course he should look the whole cable , and if its only that tip he can also cut that tip and use the intact cable left

Comment: Is "BR" Brazil or Britain or somewhere else? Locale is important for code compliance.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes it's only the tip that has the peeling nylon jacket. No exposure to gas or oil since it's going to be used in can lights not automotive work. But I am going to replace the two wires just to be safe.

Comment: @FreeMan , yes BR =Brazil, "Britain" would be "UK"